# Error while importing a function "generateToken" to a middleware in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a model and the name of the table is **users**. In the Model, i have a method **generateToken** which is used to generate the web token.
I have used sequelized ORM.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Tutorial = sequelize.define("users", {
        age: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER
        },
        name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        }
    });

    Tutorial.generateToken = async function () {
        try {
            const token = jwt.sign({ _id: this.id }, "ThisIsTaskApp")
            console.log(token)
        }
        catch (error) {
            response.send('there is an error' + error)
            console.log('there is an error' + error)
        }
    }
    return Tutorial;
};
```

I want to create a web token when my email id and password matches, so for that i have used the **generateToken** but i am getting an error

> TypeError: user.generateToken is not a function

I believe i have error with javascript importing the **generateToken** function.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const user = db.users;
const generateToken = require('./models/users')
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        await user.findOne({ where: { email: email, password: password } })
            .then(user => {
                if (user === null) {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        message: 'Auth Failed'
                    })
                }
                else {
                    const token = user.generateToken()
                    res.status(200).json(user)
                }
            })
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return res.json({ 'status': 400 })
    }
})
```

Please help me fix this issue and generating web token.

Comment: `user.generateToken()` is not using `const generateToken = require('./models/users')`. What is `db.users`? And what is `response` in your `Tutorial.generateToken`? This code seems to be pretty broken.

Comment: @Chris G const db= require('./models/users')

Comment: Try removing `const user = db.users;` and replacing `const generateToken = require('./models/users')` with `const user = require('./models/users')`

Comment: This worked for me. This is my solution

`const user = await db.users.findOne({ where: { email: email, password: password } })
        if (!user)
            return res.status(404).json({
                message: 'Auth Failed'
            })
        console.log(typeof user, user)
        const token = await user.generateToken()
        console.log("token: ", token)
        return res.status(200).json(user)`

Comment: It's not about using `user`, it's about making sure that `user` is the custom modul you wrote in the first place, and not a generic db table model.

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with your code related to async, please try this one

```
const user = db.users;

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    const userdata = await user.findOne({ where: { email: email, password: password } });

    if (userdata === null) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: "Auth Failed",
      });
    }

    const token = await userdata.generateToken();
    console.log(" ~ token", token)
    return res.status(200).json(userdata);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.json({ status: 400 });
  }
});
```

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initialization

Comment: TypeError: userdata.generateToken is not a function

Comment: well, we cant guide you symbol by symbol :) please use a debugger to find out where is the issue. make a separation into smaller parts.

Comment: also please check docs: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using

> generateToken.generateToken()

there instead of

> user.generateToken()

Because you are basically exporting the model of users in generate token variable, so that function is accessible from that variable not from user variable.

Comment: TypeError: generateToken.generateToken is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to require jsonwebtoken in /models/users as well as in the route handler file